# Rake wont load Selenium 2 unit tests anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rake, selenium-webdriver

I used to be able to launch all my Selenium2 WebDriver tests in Ruby on Rails via 'rake test:units'. But recently, my test case(s) wont be found anymore. I dont get any notification or error message. Traced, the test just ends after 'Execute test:units'

It still can be launched manually by calling 'rake test:unit TEST=test/unit/foo_bar' or using 'ruby [path]' to launch the file.

The test itself still works just fine, so I dont know why the automatic test doesn´t start anymore. I May be I violated some naming conventions? This is how everything is named:

```
File: foo_bar.rb
Class: FooBar
Method: test_foo_bar
```

Further I use some additional selfwritten requirements, stored in test/unit/helpers. Might there be another source of problems?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI: It was unconventional naming.

```
File: foo_bar_test.rb
Class: FooBarTest
Method: test_foo_bar
```

Did it right. Now everything launches again with "rake test/units".